Jest toHaveBeenCalled() doesn't work for me
I am mocking up some function:
export const natsWrapper = {
    client: {
    publish: jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementation(
        (subject: string, data: string, callback: () => void) => {
          console.log("Mock function is called");
          callback();
        }
      ),
     },
};

and then I am calling that in my test:
it("publishes an event when ticket is created", async () => {
    await request(app)
    .post("/api/tickets")
    .set("Cookie", await (global as any).signin())
    .send({ title: "title", price: 20 })
    .expect(201);

    expect(natsWrapper.client.publish).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

Jest logs in console "Mock function is called" but test still failing:
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()                             
                                                                     
    Expected number of calls: >= 1                                   
    Received number of calls:    0 


Have to mocked the nats-wrapper ?
jest.mock('../../nats-wrapper'); // Ensure the mock is used

It is correctly mocked and imported because console.log is visible @Sohan

It seems I imported mock function from __mock__ folder actually so it is not working that way, I had to import actual function which I want to mock.

This is an excellent answer, thanks! Could you update the question to add the import to your [mcve], please? (Pretend you don't know the answer yet, when editing the question.)

For "excellent" I'd expect it to show how to do that. If you no longer have the problem you could also just delete the question, given the effort required to provide something reproducible.
